# Set OG Context based on menu path

Tags: organic-groups

Trying to figure out how to create menu paths to have a custom page available for each organic group. The page for each will have unique content that will use custom logic (no views). The page should also know what the active group is based on the URL.

A few questions:

1) What path should I be using?
2) What function should I be using in my page callback to set the og context?

**I was trying to find an existing module to just inspect how they setup the callbacks and menu paths but i couldn't find anything.

```
<?php
function ogtest_menu() {

$items = array();

// not sure if this is correct. would like to be able to setup an alias so that eventually the path could be mydomain.com/mygroup/hellopage
$items['node/%/hellopage'] = array(
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'description' => 'Post a my_content_type for this group.',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'page callback' => 'ogtest_page',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
);

return $items;

function ogtest_page($args) {

  // set og context?

  $output = array();

  $output['text'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('Hello'),
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you interested in a suggestion for an alternative to OG, which may make things easier (and for which there is also already a D8 version) ...?

Comment: Sure, please fill me in

Comment: Are you using page manager / panels? Sounds like node/%/custom would work fine.